# Characterization of trivial localization of module?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $S\subset R$ be a multiplicative closed subset. Let $M$ be a R-module (may not be f.g.).

By simple deduction, we have:

> $S^{-1}M=0 \Leftrightarrow \forall m\in M,\ \mathrm{Ann}_R(m)\cap S\neq \emptyset$.

The problem is, do we have the following statement

> $S^{-1}M=0\Leftrightarrow \mathrm{Ann}_R(M)\cap S\neq\emptyset$ ?

When $M$ is finitely generated, we do have it and it's proved in this question:

[When is the localization of a module trivial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308041/when-is-the-localization-of-a-module-trivial)

Comment: No. Consider $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module and $S=\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks. That's a valid counterexample.